# What is the difference between the idioms “Feeling guilty” and “State of guilt”

Tags: expressions

I was reading the meanings of 'Culpability' and 'Contrite' on Magoosh's app, which defines them as a 'State of guilt' and 'to be remorseful' respectively.

I then wondered if there is a difference between 'being in a state of guilt' and 'feeling guilty'.

What do you guys think?

Comment: *State of guilt* refers to the fact of being responsible for an offence. *Feeling guilty*  conveys the idea of remorse for being responsible for the misdeed.

Comment: I don't think either of these are idioms, are they?

Answer (score 1):

You can be in a state of guilt without feeling it:

> They held her culpable for the accident. ([*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culpable))

So *others* can hold you culpable, whereas *feeling guilty* is what you feel yourself.

Hence, it is also possible to *feel* guilty without actually being (deemed) culpable.

> Even though nobody could have avoided the accident, she felt guilty for not saving her son.

So it's the difference between *Bob thinks that Alice is guilty* (culpability) and *Alice thinking that Alice is guilty* (feeling guilty).